# Convert rows to columns after counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table:

```
Type1 Type2
A      T1
A      T2
A      T1
A      T1
A      T2
A      T3
B      T3
B      T2
B      T3
B      T3
```

I want output as:

```
Type1 T1 T2 T3
A     3  2  1
B     0  1  3
```

I tried using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY) and CASE Statements but couldn't get desired output. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use PIVOT -

**Query 1:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Type1 CHAR(1), Type2 CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @temp (Type1, Type2)
VALUES 
     ('A', 'T1'),('A', 'T2'),
     ('A', 'T1'),('A', 'T1'),
     ('A', 'T2'),('A', 'T3'),
     ('B', 'T3'),('B', 'T2'),
     ('B', 'T3'),('B', 'T3')

SELECT *
FROM @temp
PIVOT 
(
     COUNT(Type2) FOR Type2 IN (T1, T2, T3)
) p
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
      Type1
    , T1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Type2 = 'T1' THEN 1 END)
    , T2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Type2 = 'T2' THEN 1 END)
    , T3 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Type2 = 'T3' THEN 1 END)
FROM @temp
GROUP BY Type1
```

**Output:**

```
Type1 T1          T2          T3
----- ----------- ----------- -----------
A     3           2           1
B     0           1           3
```

Comment: +1 SqlFiddle and learned something about PIVOT: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17784

Comment: +1 for you and my knowledge of `pivot` :D

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT Type1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type2='T1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type2='T2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Type2='T3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS T3
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Type1
```

Comment: +1 Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f29d/8/0

Comment: Please note that `END AS T1` is the invalid syntax.

Comment: @Devart thx , edited. +1 for my knowledge of PIVOT :D

Comment: +1 - for the good answer.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE type2 = 'T1' AND type1 = mTable1.type1) AS T1,
(SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE type2 = 'T2' AND type1 = mTable1.type1) AS T2,
(SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE type2 = 'T3' AND type1 = mTable1.type1) AS T3
FROM table1 mTable1 GROUP BY type1
```